# Empty variables in Gherkins tests

Tags: ruby

This is the output of the bundle exec cucumber run. You can see the @timeout_exception is nil during the cucumber run, but it's set fine during runtime.

```
And the output should be 'Execution Timeout Error: This deployment has taken too long to run'                                     # features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:309

  expected: "Execution Timeout Error: This deployment has taken too long to run"
       got: nil

  (compared using ==)
   (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
  ./features/step_definitions/my_steps.rb:310:in `/^the output should be '(.*)'$/'
  features/timeout_lengthy_deploys.feature:25:in `And the output should be 'Execution Timeout Error: This deployment has taken too long to run''

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/timeout_lengthy_deploys.feature:11 # Scenario: Normal deploy that times out because it takes too long
```

This is my test, but even though @timeout_exception is working during running of the code, it's empty during the test. So how can I test if this variable is set?

```
Then(/^the output should be '(.*)'$/) do |expectedException|
  expect(@timeout_exception).to eq(expectedException)
end
```

This is the Ruby code.

```
log.info "Executing '#{command.join(' ')}'"
begin
    timeout(config['deploy-timeout'].to_i) do
        execute_and_log command
    end
rescue Timeout::Error => e
    @timeout_exception = "Execution Timeout Error"
    log.error "#{@timeout_exception}"
    raise e
end
```

Log.error prints nicely "Execution Timeout Error" but is empty during the expect(@timeout_exception)...

Answer (score 1):

It's not necessarily empty during the test, but it's not accessible within the test. What you're "testing" is an instance variable belonging to the test object, not the original instance variable.

You don't say what object the instance variable belongs to, but you can retrieve the instance variable from within the test with...

```
foo.instance_variable_get(:bar)
```

But if you're testing instance variables, your test needs to know too much about the internals of your application.  Better would be for you to test whatever method uses / outputs the instance variable.